# Calculate $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n }{\sqrt{n!}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This sum is from my complex analysis booklet. It only asks for radius of convergence which I found the radius to be $R = +\infty$ by doing the following :

\begin{equation} 
S = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{\sqrt{n!}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*} 
R = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \left| \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \right| = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{(n+1)n!}}{\sqrt{n!}} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt{n+1} = +\infty
\end{equation*}

Since the sum looks similar to the series expantion of the exponential, $\displaystyle e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$, I was wondering if it is possible to get an exact value for $S$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doesn't using the ratio test for a series $\sum a_n z^n$ give $R = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \left| a_n / a_{n+1} \right|$ ?

Comment: No I think what I have put is the correct one

Comment: You will almost certainly not get a closed formula for this.

Comment: You are wrong, @fGDu94. $a_n=2^n$ has radius of convergence $1/2,$ not $2.$

Comment: There is no know closed form in terms of elementary functions. However, the asymptotics $$
S(z) \sim \sqrt {(2\sqrt {2\pi } )z} \,\exp \left( {\tfrac{1}{2}z^2 } \right)\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{16z^2 }} - \frac{{31}}{{512z^4 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$ holds as $z\to+\infty$. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.06618.pdf).

Comment: Even the value at $z=1$ [is not known in closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2FSqrt%5BGamma%5B1%2Bn%5D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D), so I seriously doubt you will be able to create a formula for general $z$.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the main term of the asymptotics can be naively obtained by switching from summation to integration and then using the Laplace method:
$$S_\alpha(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(n!)^\alpha}\sim\frac{(2\pi)^{\frac{1-\alpha}2}}{\sqrt\alpha}e^{\alpha z^{1/\alpha}}z^{\frac{1-\alpha}{2\alpha}},\,\alpha>0$$